# Debian - how to run a script on startup as soon as there is an internet connection ready for use?

Tags: debian, networking, startup

I am running Debian 7 Wheezy and I need to start some screens on startup as soon as there is a fully functional internet connection. However, not, if the internet connection broke and was connected again. So only on the first functional internet connection after boot.

Could you please post a dummy script for this and tell me where to put it and make it be executed under the given conditions?

The script only needs to start the screen and then terminate but the screen should continue.

---

**EDIT**
I have already heard of the `/etc/network/if-up.d/` folder. But how can I make sure that the script is not executed again if the internet connection is lost and then re-established?

Comment: @Celada please see the edit

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Put your script in `/etc/network/if-up.d` and make it executable. It will be automatically run each time a network interface comes up.

To make it do work only the first time it is run on every boot, have it check for existence of a flag file which you create after the first time. Example:

```
#!/bin/sh

FLAGFILE=/var/run/work-was-already-done

case "$IFACE" in
    lo)
        # The loopback interface does not count.
        # only run when some other interface comes up
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

if [ -e $FLAGFILE ]; then
    exit 0
else
    touch $FLAGFILE
fi

: here, do the real work.
```

Comment: Will the flagfile be deletet when the server shuts down?

Comment: Yes, because on Debian `/var/run` is a volatile file system (a `tmpfs`). So it's guaranteed to come up empty at every fresh boot.

Comment: Just to be over-precise: Is there a chance that the script will be executed concurrently? So that the `real work` might happen several times if the script is executed concurrently?

Comment: Good catch. I think you'd have to be really unlucky, but I think yes, because of hot-plugged interfaces that could be brought up simultaneously. So I guess you can do this atomically instead of test-then-create, which would make it safe, but what I came up with off the top of my head isn't pretty! `python -c 'import os; os.open("/var/run/work-was-already-done", os.O_EXCL|os.O_CREAT, 0)' 2>/dev/null || exit 0`

Comment: Is there also some way to use lock files to synchronize the stuff?

Comment: Yes, you could wrap the test in a lock file instead (check out the `flock` command, designed for use in shell scripts), but the POSIX `open()` system call provides a way to do it atomically without the need for lock files: the `O_EXCL` flag I used. It causes the file to be created if it doesn't exist, or else the `open()` will fail. It's just that I know of no standard shell command that makes use of `O_EXCL`, hence the Python one-liner.

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock If you use Celada's script as is, your code will run as soon as the loopback interface comes up. If you want to wait for internet connectivity, at least check that `IFACE` is not `lo` — or some virtual interface — or better, test for Internet connectivity by pinging .

Comment: @Gilles Thanks for pointing that out. I edited the answer. Your other suggestions are also good.

Comment: @Gilles What values can `IFACE` have?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock `$IFACE` can have as values any interface that comes up. You can list all of the interfaces that exist with `ip link` or look at which ones are configured to be brought up by scanning `/etc/network/interfaces`

Comment: @Celada Where is the output of the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d/` saved?

Comment: @MinecraftShamrock The output will be saved nowhere in particular: it probably goes to the stdio of whatever ran `ifup` (e.g. startup scripts or udev). If you want to save the output you'll have to send it to a log file yourself.

Comment: if `/etc/network/if-up.d` and `/etc/network/if-down.d` are not working, people should try `/etc/network/if-pre-up.d/` and `/etc/network/if-post-down.d` https://askubuntu.com/questions/62366/networkmanager-if-down-d-script-does-not-execute/74799#74799

Comment: I get this error `touch: cannot touch '/var/run/work-was-already-done': Permission denied`

Comment: Is this technique deprecated?

Answer (score 15):

This is a job very well suited for [`systemd`](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html).

#### Running a script as a systemd service

If your system is running [systemd](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html), then you can configure your script to run as a systemd service which provides control over the lifecycle and execution environment, as well as preconditions for starting the script, such as the network being up and running, restarting on failure, etc.

The recommended folder for your own services is `/etc/systemd/system/` (another option is `/lib/systemd/system` but that should normally be used for OOTB services only).

Create the file e.g. with `sudo vim /etc/systemd/system/autossh.service` :

```conf
[Unit]
Description=Autossh keepalive daemon
## make sure we only start the service after network is up
Wants=network-online.target
After=network.target

[Service]
## here we can set custom environment variables
Environment=AUTOSSH_GATETIME=0
Environment=AUTOSSH_PORT=0
# By default type 'simple' is used, see also https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Type=
# Type=simple|exec|forking|oneshot|dbus|notify|idle
ExecStart=/usr/local/bin/ssh-keep-alive.sh
ExecStop=pkill -9 autossh
# don't use 'nobody' if your script needs to access user files
# (if User is not set the service will run as root)
#User=nobody

# Useful during debugging; remove it once the service is working
StandardOutput=console

[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Now you can test the service:

```bash
sudo systemctl start autossh
```

Checking the status of the service:

```bash
systemctl status autossh
```

Stopping the service:

```bash
sudo systemctl stop autossh
```

Once you verified that the service works as expected enable it with:

```bash
sudo systemctl enable autossh
```

> <sup>NOTE: For security purposes `systemd` will run the script in a restricted environment, similar to how `crontab` scripts are run, therefore don't make any assumptions about pre-existing system variables such as $PATH or whatever you have in your `/.bashrc`, `~/.zshrc`, etc. Use the `Environment` keys if your script needs specific variables to be defined. Adding `set -x` at the top of your bash script and then running `systemctl status my_service` might help identify why your script is failing. As a rule of tumb, always use [absolute paths](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/systemd.service.html#Command%20lines) for everything including `echo`, or explicitly define your $PATH by adding `Environment=MYVAR=abc`.</sup>

Answer (score 2):

The internet connection is brought up by an entry in `/etc/rc6.d/` probably `S35networking`. If you change that file and insert your commands at the end, or better add a `/etc/init.d/mystuff` and link `/etc/rc0.d/S36mystuff` to it and insert your commands there, then that will start as soon as the network is up.

Comment: Will it be called if the connection is lost and then re-established? Because otherwise I could just put the script into `/etc/network/if-up.d`

Comment: No this is just at startup

Comment: That will work, but just for correctness let me point out that no script in `/etc/rc0.d` will be run at startup, those will run at shutdown (run level 0). At startup it would be something in `/etc/rc2.d` or similar. Specifically for the OP's Debian wheezy, it's `/etc/rcS.d/S12networking`. It all symlinks to the same file, of course. Also BTW @Anthon thanks for fixing my answer: "Please" instead of "Put"? What a weird typo!

Comment: @Celada Your right it's rc6 on my (non-Debian system). I was not sure if you wanted 'Please put' there, but just "Put" seemed more crispy. BTW I upvoted your answer, it is just a better approach for networking as it has that `if-up.d` as generic mechanism that also works on a reconnect.