# No output when running script on startup (but correct output if run manually)

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, write

I recently got myself a Raspberry Pi 2 to learn a couple of things in my spare time. It is now running on Raspbian and I control it remotely via ssh from a laptop with Linux Mint 17.2 installed.

Now I would like the Pi to automatically tell the laptop that it is online after a reboot so that I know that I can connect to it via ssh. I know I can just wait a few seconds or ping the Pi, but somehow I got it into my head that it would be nice if a small message popped up in my terminal on the laptop.

What I got so far after some tinkering is the following (I'm VERY new to this, so I'm not even aware of the levels this might be horribly wrong on):

```
/usr/bin/ssh 'laptop_user'@'laptop_ip' "echo '### RaspberryPi 2 online ###' | /usr/bin/write 'laptop_user' pts/0"
```

This works when run in a terminal on the Pi if my laptop has the IP 'laptop_ip' and if 'laptop_user' is logged in on `pts/0` (lots of if's, but I figured I would get to those after I got the initial idea up and running). On the laptop terminal something like

```
Message from 'laptop_user'@'laptop_host' on pts/0 at 09:58:
### RaspberryPi 2 online ###
EOF
```

appears. (yeah!)

I then put the command into a small script:

```
#! /bin/sh
/usr/bin/ssh 'laptop_user'@'laptop_ip' "echo '### RaspberryPi 2 online ###' | /usr/bin/write 'laptop_user' pts/0"
exit 0
```

saved it as `/etc/network/if-up.d/sayhi` on the Pi, and made it executable (following the best answer on [this question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/166473/debian-how-to-run-a-script-on-startup-as-soon-as-there-is-an-internet-connecti)). I checked that this script does indeed get executed after each reboot of the Pi. The thing is, if I run the script manually everything works fine and I get the message on my laptop terminal. But if the script is automatically executed on reboot I don't get the message. Putting the command into `rc.local` or `crontab` didn't work either.

I unfortunately lack the knowledge of how a startup of the Pi (or any computer) actually works. So I don't know if the services required for this command are already good to go.

So my question is:

Why don't I get the "online" message when the script is run automatically and when should I run my little script to achieve the desired behavior.

Also, there might be way better alternatives to my way of doing this. So if anyone could point me in the right direction I'd appreciate it.

Thanks in advance!

**edit:**

- I forgot to mention that I'm using key authentication and as the script will be run as the Pi's `root` I added its public RSA key to `authorized_keys` on the laptop and I'm using the private key as the identify file for the `ssh` command.
- I'm now logging the output of `/sbin/ip addr` while running the script on startup and if gives me:

  `eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST> mtu 1500 qdisc noop state DOWN group default qlen 1000 link/ether b8:27:eb:34:66:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff`

  When running the script later (manually over ssh) `/sbin/ip addr` gives me:

  `eth0: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc pfifo_fast state UP group default qlen 1000 link/ether b8:27:eb:34:66:ce brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff 
  inet 192.168.0.105/24 brd 192.168.0.255 scope global eth0 valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever`

  So the problem seems to be that the Pi does not have a local IP while running the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d`. I now have to run my script after  the IP is assigned. Unfortunately, I don't know enough about networking to be able to do so.

Comment: Hey, Welcome to UnixSE. Feel free to take a [tour](unix.stackexchange.com/tour) of the community. You mentioned you're monitoring from laptop with Mint. So, I'd rather send a desktop notification with `notify-send` than `write`. But, maybe that's because I haven't used write much.

Comment: I'd say this is because startup scripts are run as root and you are using your local public key as login with your normal user? You need to add the /root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub as trusted if so is the case. I can write an answer in a few min explaining it but I'm on the phone now

Comment: @Bibek_G That looks exactly like the thing I'm looking for. It won't resolve the network/script issue (I guess) but I will definitely look into this. Thanks!

Comment: @Torxed I think I get it and you might very well be right. Will test this as soon as possible. Thanks!

Comment: Which user's crontab did you use? How do you authenticate on your laptop with SSH: do you use a key? Does it have a password?

Comment: @Gilles I'm using the root user's `crontab` and private RSA key for authentication. The public key is added to the `authorized_keys` on the laptop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Most likely this is because your startup script will run in a root environment by default.
Assuming that you're using `~/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` as your mode of authentication *(You never mentioned that you're using a password and using such a thing while automate is often a bad idea anyway, so i'll assume key authentication)*.

Then I'll go ahead and assume even further that you haven't allowed the (or even have a) root key generated that is trusted on your laptop?

You have two options in this case.

1. run `ssh-keygen` as root, and copy the content of  `/root/.ssh/id_rsa.pub` to your `/home/<user>/.ssh/authorized_keys` file.

or

2. change your command to `/usr/bin/ssh -i /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 'laptop_user'@'laptop_ip' "echo '### RaspberryPi 2 online ###' | /usr/bin/write 'laptop_user' pts/0"`

The second is neater since it uses your users certificate that you already know works.

### debian startup order and network connectivity issue

Most likely (after reading your comments) this is a script startup order issue, meaning that your script is run betwork network.d has had a chance to DHCP your interface and bring it up.

even `rc.local` is run after `network.target` but that's not the same as `network-online.target` sorry to say.

You have again a few options here, one is to simply add this to your `crontab` line:

```
@reboot sleep 60 && /usr/bin/ssh -i /home/<user>/.ssh/id_rsa.pub 'laptop_user'@'laptop_ip' "echo '### RaspberryPi 2 online ###' | /usr/bin/write 'laptop_user' pts/0"
```

Which will sleep your command for 60 seconds before executing the SSH command.
It's not the most pretty thing in the world, but if you don't care about real time "notifications" go with it, it's quick and it works.

**If you want a more reliable options tho**, i'd suggest you create a `init.d` script with a target requirement for `network-online.target` which won't trigger your init script until the network is online. This is the most fastest and reliable option to go with.

I use `systemd` so I can't write or verify a proper `init.d` script atm, try following this guide and see if it works: https://www.debian-administration.org/article/28/Making_scripts_run_at_boot_time_with_Debian

Comment: Unfortunately, neither of those options works. Also: the identify file (-i) should be the private key, right?

Comment: @nieswand You are correct, that should be the private file! Humm, this is most peculiar. under which `crontab -e` are you doing this? Can you, in your script do `whoami > ~/whoami.log` and check that file for the users name? Are you sure this script is being run after your have your network up? You can double-check this by adding `ip addr > ~/ip.log` at the top of your script. Remember the RPi is quite slow so it might be that the DHCP havn't fully gotten an IP yet.

Comment: I'm using root's  `crontab -e`. I added `whoami` and `ip addr` to `crontab -e`, `etc/rc.local`, and `/etc/network/if-up.d/sayhi` (one after another) and they all yield `root` as user. The `ip.log` in all three cases tells me that `eth0` is down and has no local IP, yet. Even the `if-up.d` script. I also added `post-up /etc/network/if-up.d/sayhi` to the `eth0` interface in `/etc/network/interfaces`. Still, `ip.log` says `eth0` is down. BUT: If I only restart my network connection (and not the Pi itself) with `sudo /etc/init.d/networking restart`, then `eth0` is shown as up in `ip.log`

Comment: I followed the instructions given on the page you linked to. It changes nothing on the outcome of my script. I also added a sleep time, but no matter how long I let the script sleep, the outcome is always the same. In fact, I can't log in via ssh during the sleep time. So it seems that the setup of the IP is delayed until after my script has finished. So sleeping is not a solution

Comment: That was an error on my end. `sleep` now works for me. Since it is just a small feature that might be replaced with something more suitable as soon as I learn a bit more about Linux, this quick fix will do. Thanks a lot! Since I'm new to this: Should I change the question? Because the actual problem changed somewhat during the discussion.

Comment: @nieswand pleasure was all mine! Welcome to Stack Unix btw. Best of luck

Answer (score 0):

You need to tell `ssh` to create a terminal device on the target box, so that `write` will work. You do this with the `-t` flag. Twice.

```
ssh -tt 'laptop_user'@'laptop_ip' "echo '### RaspberryPi 2 online ###' | /usr/bin/write 'laptop_user' pts/0"
```

Comment: As I mentioned, `write` (and the whole command/script) does work. Just not when run on startup. I now believe that the reason is that the Pi does not have a local IP when the scripts in `/etc/network/if-up.d` are run.