# Wrong time after reboot pop_os

Tags: networking, date, pop-os

I'm currently working on a dual system pc windows(legacy) and Pop_!Os(UFEI).

recently, I've been facing a time problem which on windows is not present but whenever I reboot the device the Linux time and date would get messed up!.
NOTE **both windows and Linux are installed on separate disks and have different UFEI partitions.**

what I did is the following:

1. I made the command `date`doesn't require a password from the user and then I followed this [post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/166478).

The executable script called `time` that I wrote in the `if-up.d` directory contains:

```
#!/bin/sh

FLAGFILE=/var/run/work-was-already-done

case "$IFACE" in
    lo)
        # The loopback interface does not count.
        # only run when some other interface comes up
        exit 0
        ;;
    *)
        ;;
esac

if [ -e $FLAGFILE ]; then
    exit 0
else
    touch $FLAGFILE
fi


sudo date -s "$(curl -s --head http://bing.de | grep '^Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 3-)"

echo $(date) >> /home/myPop/Desktop/timeLog.txt

sudo date -s "$(wget -qSO- --max-redirect=0 http://google.com 2>&1 | grep '^  Date:' | cut -d' ' -f 5-)"

echo $(date) >> /home/myPop/Desktop/timeLog.txt
```

upon calling the command `sudo ifup --all`-v` I got the following:

```
ifup: reading directory /etc/network/interfaces.d
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-pre-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wireless-tools
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-pre-up.d/wpasupplicant
/bin/run-parts --exit-on-error --verbose /etc/network/if-up.d
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/000resolvconf
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/avahi-autoipd
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/openvpn
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/time
run-parts: executing /etc/network/if-up.d/wpasupplicant
```

when executing it the correct date and time will be written in the log file on the desktop.
YET when I reboot I would see that the data produced by both the `wget` and the `curl` approach would fail to correct the time and will produce the following according to the date of today:

```
Thu Oct 15 00:00:00 CEST 2020
Thu Oct 15 00:00:00 CEST 2020
```

it baffles me why these two commands produce the wrong time while booting but give the right answers when executed after the desktop is shown.

2. I deleted the `/etc/adjtime` file as instructed in this [site](http://www.openeloquence.com/sdb/html/954237377.html) yet without any difference at all.
3. I suspected that the time in my bios might be wrong but I doubled checked and it is correct.
4. Im no expert so i suspected as well that the router might have been giving me the wrong time information but since i live in a student dorm and i dont have any access to the router as a device I can't check that, so I went to my `system setting-> date & time-> Automatic date & time` and disabled it so now theoretically the device won't take the time data from the router if that's ever possible.

please, suggest what I shall do? I'm open to all suggestions at this time :).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Welcome, is the time of linux OS right? It happens in dual boot that time gets messed up...

Comment: @schrodigerscatcuriosity, as I stated in the post the windows, is not affected just the Linux both windows and Linux are installed on separate disks.