# How can I mount partitions based on IP?

Tags: networking, nfs, fstab

I have set up a home server and I was wondering if it is possible to set up the `fstab` to automatically mount the network drive using the home network IP when I am at home and to mount it using my Tailscale IP when I am outside of my home network.

This is my current `fstab`:

```
#
# /etc/fstab
# Created by anaconda on Tue Jun 21 16:36:27 2022
#
# Accessible filesystems, by reference, are maintained under '/dev/disk/'.
# See man pages fstab(5), findfs(8), mount(8) and/or blkid(8) for more info.
#
# After editing this file, run 'systemctl daemon-reload' to update systemd
# units generated from this file.
#
UUID=[REDACTED] /                       btrfs   subvol=root,compress=zstd:1 0 0
UUID=[REDACTED] /boot                   ext4    defaults        1 2
UUID=[REDACTED] /boot/efi               vfat    umask=0077,shortname=winnt 0 2
UUID=[REDACTED] /home                   btrfs   subvol=home,compress=zstd:1 0 0
# BEGIN ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
[HOMENETWORK]:/homeserver/encrypted/backups   /mnt/backups            nfs     defaults 0 0
# END ANSIBLE MANAGED BLOCK
```

Comment: Ideally, you would set things up so that you can reach your home network via the tailscale VPN, so that you can simply use the home network IP in all cases (and let the kernel figure out how to route the connection).

Comment: I believe that what you want is not possible in the way that you want it. A possible work around would be to add a script that mounts the network drive after networking has started. You can have a look at [running a script as a systemd service](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/401080/520479) which can provide what you need.

Comment: @larsks Thanks. I read a bit about this on Tailscale's website and, from what I can tell, that'd anyway go through the Internet. I think I might make a `systemd` service, as @ttsakpc suggested.